# Split a sentence using multiple characters?

Tags: c#, arrays, split

I have an input box to input sentences, and I want to split it at every specific character. I have done this for `.`:

```
 var ArraySourceTexts = textbox.Text.Split(new Char[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

My question is, what if I have multiple character? for example I want it split if the sentences contains the characters: `.`, `?`, `!`.

Please share!

Comment: Not sure what is the problem... You are already using the array overload - so specify more items: `new Char[] { '.' ,'?','!'}`

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you trying to achieve? Can you please provide examples and desired output?

Comment: if I have example like this:

input text : this is an example. Please check, and let me know your thoughts!

so I want to split the sentences from textbox indicates by "." and ",".

So I want the output to have 3 array. 
`
1. this is an example. 
2. Please check, 
3. and let me know your thoughts!`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `string.Split` with a `Char` array, you can specify as many characters as you want within that array. Just add more characters which will cause the split:

```
char[] splitChars = new char[] { '.', '!', '?', ',' };
var ArraySourceTexts = textbox.Text.Split(splitChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Input:

`this is an example. Please check, and let me know your thoughts!`

Output:

```
[0] this is an example 
[1] Please check 
[2] and let me know your thoughts
```

---

**Method 2**: If you want to split the string but **keep** the seperators (like you mentioned in the comments):

```
string[] arr = Regex.Split(textbox.Text, @"(?<=[.,!?])");
```

Input:

`this is an example. Please check, and let me know your thoughts!`

Output:

```
[0] this is an example.
[1] Please check, 
[2] and let me know your thoughts!
```